# Calculate Continuous Enrollment 12 months before and after reference date

Tags: sql, date, db2, sas, continuous

I am new to claims data and relatively new to SQL...and would greatly appreciate your help.

I have data similar to this:

```
Customer    Group   Member  ServiceDt
ABCDE       123     1111    01-Jan-12
            123     1111    01-Feb-12
            123     1111    01-Mar-12
            123     1112    01-Feb-12
            123     1112    01-Mar-12
FGHIJ       456     1116    01-Feb-12
KLMNO       567     1117    01-Mar-12
            678     1118    01-Feb-12
            789     1119    01-Mar-12
```

A member can have one entry per month to indicate active enrollment date. So, a member can have 24 rows for two years' worth of enrollment. Another could have just five rows and so on...Each member is a part of a group who in turn are a part of a customer. (A customer could have multiple groups - with many members in each group and each member has a row per month).

I need to evaluate continuous enrollment from the service date going back 12 months and then going ahead 12 months ( an year of enrollment before and after the service date) and then roll it up to group by CUSTOMER and GROUP numbers.

I have tried intck/intcx functions but seem to be doing something wrong. When I try the first. and last. way, I am getting lost. This data is so new to me.:)

Here are snippets of the code (not including the server connection stuff) I tried so far:

```
beg1ylag = intnx('month',&eff ,-12,'m');
add1yfut = intnx('month',&eff , 12,'m');

If first.member_id then do;
    mth_cnt     = 0;
    lag_mth_cnt = 0;
    fut_mth_cn  = 0;
End;

 mth_cnt+1;
  if eff_dt < servicedt then lag_mth_cnt+1;
  if eff_dt > servicedt then fut_mth_cnt+1;

  if last.member_id then output;


Proc SQL;
Select (x,y,z

 beg1ylag = intnx('month',servicedt,-12,'m');
 add1yfut = intnx('month',servicedt, 12,'m');

call symput('_beg1ylag',cats("'",year(beg1ylag),'-',put(month(beg1ylag),z2.),"Middle'"));
call symput('_add1yfut',cats("'",year(add1yfut),'-',put(month(add1yfut),z2.),"Middle'"));
Quit;
```

The result I get is empty rows. I don't know what I am doing or doing wrong....please guide me. Also, please note that the serviced is NOT fixed. Each member can have a different one - as you can see above. Ultimately, I need to be able to pick members and group them by their group number if they have had 24 months of continuous membership around the servicedt.

Comment: Would you mind providing an expected output?

Comment: Please give details of your input data tables.  Please be precise about rules for 12 months past and future.  What type of healthcare claims are you dealing with, and is this insurance in U.S.?  The requirements you've given seem extremely simplistic for health insurance, and the numerous factors and situations that can be involved.  What is business  reason for the 12 months of future coverage, and what are those requirements?

Comment: Where does your macro variable `&eff` come from? Are you looking for members having enrolled continuously from 12 months before till 12 months after a certain date? (That's 25 months, not 24!) Unless you are involved in big data, why do you ad the [ds2] tag? Why do you tag your question as [continuous]? It has nothing to do with this statistical concept.

Comment: @yukclam9: I will put together a table in a little. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @WarrenT: The present table is enrollment related, in a US healthcare insurance system. There are several other requirements but for the purposes of my analysis, I am stuck here but have resolved other parts of the query that I needed to. The business customer wants some summary of trends that need me to compare the before and after. About the 12 months, they insist on uninterrupted coverage for the previous 12 months and 12 in the future. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @DirkHorsten: Yes this is 'big data'. The servicedt is NOT standard. Each group (and all its members) will have the same but considering I have about 50 groups and millions of rows with 30-60 rows per member, I used the &eff to point to the servicedt. Apologies for omitting it n the code. Yes, you are right - it will be 25 months. Thanks for pointing that.  However, this is 'continuous' since the 25 months' membership has to be uninterrupted - even for a month. I am okay with the statistics part of things - just am stuck in the logic querying. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Can I assume that failing to have 12 months prior &12 months future coverage is not going to prevent payment of a claim?  There are plenty of legitimate reasons for not satisfying that criteria, yet they would still need to be paid. Case in point, a newborn infant would not have 12 months prior coverage.

Comment: @WarrenT: Agree with your logic and that has been accounted for. This, however is more from an analytic stand point and has no effect on claim disbursement (or at least it is well above my lowly paygrade and I sincerely hope that does not happen here or anywhere).

Comment: **If it is big data** and data size becomes an issue, you should tell us on what platform and in which structure the data is available.

Answer (score 0):

If I interpret your question well, you need

```
%let eff = '01Feb2012'd;
%let span = 12;

Title "Members enrolled continuously from &span months before &eff till &span months after &eff";
proc sql;
    select Customer, Group, Member
    from   enrol
    where  ServiceDt between intnx('month',&eff ,-&span,'b') and intnx('month',&eff ,+&span,'b')
    group by Customer, Group, Member
    having count(*) EQ 1 + INTCK('month', intnx('month',&eff ,-&span,'b'), intnx('month',&eff ,+&span,'b'));
quit;
```

Note that you should use intnx with 'b' for beginning, not 'm' for middle as your data mentions begin of month dates too.

Comment: Thank you @DirkHosten. I will try this suggestion and update the group. My apologies about the 'm'. I was typing a dummy list for the board and without thinking through - went with beginning dates. In my data, the date is consistently the 15th of the month and hence I used the 'm'.

Comment: Actually the having clause could better be written as `count(*) EQ %eval(1 + 2 * &span)`

Answer (score 0):

If your source data is in a SAS dataset and you can run SAS code on the server where the data resides, the following is extremely efficient.

```
%let span = 12;

Data Continuous (keep=Customer Group Member eff);
    set Service;
    by Customer Group Member ServiceDt;
```

** For each new member or interuption of service 
start a new Continuous service interval **;

```
    retain From;
    if first.Member or dif(ServiceDt) GT 31 
        then From = ServiceDt;
```

** If service started at least 2 span months ago
then span months ago is the centre
of a sufficiently long continuous service interval **;

```
    if INTCK('month', From, ServiceDt) GE %eval(2 * &span) then do;
        eff = intnx('month', ServiceDt,-&span,'b');
        output;
    end;
run;
```

It gives your results for every possible service interval centre (=eff) at once.

Comment: Thank you for your time and input @Dirk Horstern. Yes, my source is a SAS data file. I will try this code today and update the board. I could not do it sooner as there was another issue to deal with.